# Vertical Gaps Appearing - jQuery Masonry - (seamless photo grid)

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid, photo-gallery, jquery-masonry

This question has already been asked in a [different situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239423/help-with-jquery-masonry-minor-tweak).

I am trying to achieve a seamless photo grid with jQuery Masonry.

Check out my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/drw158/sAkjv/

There is a vertical gap. **Why?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display your images as block-level elements:

```
.ct-coll-item img {
  display: block;
}
```

See if this works: http://jsfiddle.net/drw158/sAkjv/1/

As for the why, I have no idea. My guess would be because the images are inline elements, but that isn't a direct explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your doctype. Change it to **XHTML 1.0 Transitional** then everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

You should make the `<img/>` a float.