# jQuery Masonry plugin vertical gaps

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I am working on a site trying to implement the Masonry jQuery plugin. From what is advertised for masonry there should be no, or at least minimal, vertical gaps; however I can't seem to get rid of the gaps on the site I'm working on.

I've followed the instructions for masonry exactly, all .js files are linked correctly and as far as I can tell masonry is working, albeit bizarrely.

I've tried the solution from [Vertical Gaps Appearing - jQuery Masonry - (seamless photo grid)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579017/vertical-gaps-appearing-jquery-masonry-seamless-photo-grid) and added display: block; CSS to the site to absolutely no effect, I've also tried re-arranging the order of the images but the same problem occurs. The site I'm working on can be seen here: http://www.zinestudio.co.uk/penarthphysio/gallery.html

thanks for any help!

Comment: where's Masonry being used? The gallery you link to is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for this, the client who needed an answer to this went ahead and changed it all so it is no longer required. Thanks for the interest though Chris!